# Thresholding from a set of 2D points

Tags: regression, distributions, computer-vision, threshold

In real world situations, most often the estimated 2D positions from the videos are effected by a noise.

I have a set of consecutive 2D positions for moving objects in 2D space. 
Part of this data (1000 observations) were annotated that the object is stationary (standing still).
I would like to use this data (1000 observations) to define a ***threshold r*** around the zero. So, for example, if the change in the position of the object between two consecutive observations *<= r*; the object consider to be stationary.

In my current approach, I first calculate the absolute differences between each consecutive observations (or positions). Then, I calculated the following measures: mean, median, maximum, minimum, and the standard deviations of the absolute differences. Note that the absolute differences are not normally distributed.

My first question, what is the best way to define ***r*** ?
Second, can I use ***r = standard deviation (STD)*** of the differences?